# Battery issue with MacBook Pro 13 inch (Early 2011)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, power

So, around June 2011 I finally had the chance to buy my first Macbook Pro (13 inches, i5)

But recently, I've noticed something wrong with my battery!

Actually with only 2 months of use, I was under Boot Camp doing random stuff when I saw something like "98% fully charged" (battery icon in the menu bar)and didn't pay attention to that until now.

Now, with around 40 cycles, my battery is showing 94/95% (5412-5450 mAh)

Any ideas? I think my battery is defective =/

Answer (score 1):

> The built-in battery of your MacBook, MacBook Pro or MacBook Air is designed to deliver up to 1000 full charge and discharge cycles before it reaches 80 percent of its original capacity.
>   [Link.](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html)

Little differences in capacity are normal and are no indicator for a defect battery. Only contact Apple when your battery performes worse than the design capacity.

Comment: "1000 cycles till it reaches 80%" Im at 40~ cycles with 6% consumed O_O that's my problem =[

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a calibration issue. The easiest way to recalibrate is to leave the MacBook on until it sleeps because of low battery. Leave it off for an hour and then recharge fully (no interruptions and use OSX).  Use [CoconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/) or similar tool to monitor and log your battery status. My prediction is that it'll update the health to at least 98%.

[image: Battery statistics for my MBP]